# Como solucionar el error: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto. C#

Tags: c#

por favor podrían ayudarme antes estaba ejecutando normal pero de repente empezó a salirme este error. ¿Cuál sería la solución?

private void CalcularTotales()
{
double total = 0, MontoTotal = 0, inversion = 0, TotalInversion = 0, restante = 0, totalRestante = 0;

for (int x = 0; x < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; x++)
{

```
            if (Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[9].Value) == "ACTIVO")
            {
                inversion = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value);
                restante = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value);
                total = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value);
                TotalInversion += inversion;
                totalRestante += restante;
                MontoTotal += total;
            }

        }
        lblMontoInversion.Text = TotalInversion.ToString("N2");
        lblInversionRestante.Text = totalRestante.ToString("N2");
        lblGanaciaTotal.Text = MontoTotal.ToString("N2");
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, todo código debe ser escrito y no enviado por fotos y con respecto a tu pregunta, esta recibiendo un valor nulo `dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cell[9].Value`

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.